# Finding parent frame of the event

Tags: javascript, jquery, frames

I have multiple frames with attached keydown events. 
When I press key I need to find which frame fired this event.

I tried to do so:

```
function initHotKeys(invokedFrameDocument) {
    $(invokedFrameDocument).keydown(
    function(e) {
        $(e.target).closest(frame);
    });
}

initHotKeys(window.frames['frame1'].document);
initHotKeys(window.frames['frame2'].document);
initHotKeys(window.frames['frame3'].document);
```

but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try to change:

```
$(e.targe)
```

to:

```
$(e.target)
```

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo, when I copy pasted my code. I trying to use $(e.target) and it's not working

Comment: I cannot post exact code, but I tried to show concept of what I'm doing

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(e.target).closest("frame");
```

Comment: I had to try use "frame" with quotes at first. But it doesn't work too.